# Facebook wall not visible to all

Tags: android, facebook

Hello i am using below code to post wall to my facebook,it adds the wall to my facebook but

not visible to my friends.
how can i do this

```
public void postOnWall(String songtitle,String artist,String location,String desc) {
    String msg=desc+" at "+location+" listening to "+songtitle+" by "+artist;
    String description="Share your memories with the all new social map!";
     try {
            String response;
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message",msg);
            parameters.putString("description",description);
            parameters.putString("link","");
            parameters.putString("name","");
            response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");

            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
               Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Snippet to make your Post visible to all user :

```
       try{
         String msg=desc+" at "+location+" listening to "+songtitle+" by "+artist;
         String description="Share your memories with the all new social map!";
         Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
         JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

         try {
            attachment.put("name", "");
            attachment.put("href", link);
            attachment.put("message",msg);
            attachment.put("description",description);
         } catch (JSONException e) {    }   
         parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
         parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
         parameters.putString("target_id", "Your Used ID"); // Optional
         String  response = mFacebook.request(parameters);       
      }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a string called `privacy` to your parameters like this:

```
       parameters.putString("privacy","friends");
```

for more information, try reading the [Facebook Post reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: i added above parameter also.if i add this wall is not posting to facebok